# Folland corollary 7.13

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Consider the following fragments from Folland's text "Real analysis":

[image]

I don't see how corollary 7.13 follows from the other two listed propositions. My attempt was to define
$$\mathcal{G}:= \{g \in C_c(X): 0 \leq g \leq f\}$$
but I can't show that this set consists of lower semi continuous functions.

How do I deduce corollary 7.13 from the other two propositions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cor 7.13 follows immediately from 7.11 e) and 7.12 by taking $\mathcal G$ to be $\{g:\in C_c(X): 0 \leq g \leq f\}$.  Every continuous function is lower (as well as upper) semi-continuous.  $\{x: f (x) >a\}$ is the inverse image under $f$ of $(a,\infty)$ so it is open.

Comment: And this is directed because if $g_1 \leq f, g_2 \leq f$, then $\max\{g_1, g_2\} \leq f?$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @user745578

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can't believe I didn't realize that continuous functions were semicontinuous...